# How to get string from object which contains multiple arrays?

Tags: php

I'm newbie to PHP and trying to get a string from mysql query result.

I'm run this code:

```
$results = $query->rows;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

And get this result:

```
Array
(
)

Array
(
)

Array
(
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location] => someaddress
        )

)
```

How can I get 'someaddress' to string?

Comment: That can't be the result, because you only have one `print_r()`.  This output shows the output of four `print_r()` invocations.

Comment: Is `print_r` in a loop, or is the result part of a wrapped array? If it's a wrapped array, such as `array( array (), array() ...)`, then simply loop through and find one that is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($results as $key=>$val){
  echo $val['location'] . "<br/>";
}
```

no need to convert to string.simply iterate to the loop and store all location to some array if more are there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($results as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['location'] . "<br/>";
}
```